# Database/SQL: Is attribute/key name for table unique?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In database, can I use the same attribute name for multiple tables, but the description of the attribute name are not necessary the same?  For example, i have the following tables for a furniture store:

```
Table1(itemID, type)

 - type = car, tv, furniture

Table2(custID, type)

 - type = new member, vip    
 - I know I could re-name "type" to something like membership_type, but for this example, let's assume the above is the attribute name that I'm using.
```

Can I use type as an attribute name in both table?

Just like the above, in SQL, are key names unique?  Can I use the same key name for multiple tables, but have different use for that key name?

Comment: Of course, you can use it for multiple tables with different use.

Comment: the attribute name is unique for a table not for different tables, you can have the same name of attribute for two tables

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I use type as an attribute name in both table?
```

Yes

```
in SQL, are key names unique?
```

In SQL you designate 1 or more columns to form the Primary Key. Each column name is unique in a given table. You can't have 2 columns in the same table called type. When you specify that a column name is a Primary Key, something called a constraint (with default name) is created for you that default name is unique and you can choose its name too but most probably you don't want to worry about it now.

```
 Can I use the same key name for multiple tables, but have different use for that key name?
```

Yes.

If you use 2 tables in a query and you want to list 2 columns with the same name, you need to tell the database about that - Example:

```
SELECT ItemID, T1.Type, CustID, T2.Type
From Table1 T1, Table2 T2
```

Here we had to distinguish between Type in table1 and Type in table2 by using T1.Type and T2.Type.